# What are the advantages and disadvantages of being a woman in Mount and Blade: Warband

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I would like to know if there are any advantages or more disadvantages of being a woman in *Mount and Blade: Warband*. I know for example you need more points to become vassal (I believe it's called) and you need more points to get a fiev. Now I also know its harder to become an actual king. Are there any advantages of being a woman?

Comment: Advantage for Steam users: there are quite a bit of Steam achievements only for female characters (e.g. Girl Power, Talk of the town, Man Eater, Queen, Empress, Lady of the Lake, Man Handler).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I have never played Mount and Blade. The following information was gained entirely through secondary sources.*

When you play as a female character, your starting stats will change - you will, relative to a male character, have +1 AGI and +1 INT, but -1 STR and -1 CHA [1]. In addition, a woman of noble background will have different starting skills to  a man of noble background: women will get Riding, Wound Treatment, and First Aid instead of Power Strike and Tactics [2]. A similiar change in starting skills applies to a woman of nomad background compared to the male counterpart.

As a female character, you will need more Renown to do things. The base requirement to join a faction is 150 for men, but 200 for women[3]. In addition, it is more difficult to get a fief as a woman, unless you have a large amount of Renown (700). If you play as a woman, the lord who owns the castle associated with your village granted to you will deny you entry into his castle [4].

The marriage system for men and women is also different. The system for marriage for women may be considered simpler, but possibly more difficult [5]. It is very direct - find the lord you want to marry, increase your relationship with him, and then ask to "cement the alliance to their house". The wiki page suggests that a female character "may gain more from a marriage than her male counterpart", but it doesn't elaborate on this. One last thing: female characters also can marry a Hero, which male characters cannot do [6].

Altogether, it seems like playing as a woman is overall a disadvantage [7], as it seems the cons outweigh the pros.

[1]: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Player
[2]: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Character_creation
[3]: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Renown
[4]: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Fiefs
[5]: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage
[6]: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes
[7]: http://www.gog.com/forum/general/mount_and_blade_warband_female_character_confusion

Comment: Hmm i have to try to marry a hero now ;) Thanks for taking the time to accumilate your answer.

Comment: One advantage this answer misses, and probably the biggest advantage available to a female character, is that choosing the Lady in Waiting background gives the character a Spirited Courser, one the best mounts in the game. As the game can be quite hard at the start this is a significant advantage. Overall I found playing a female character in the original M&B game not that difficult, so I wouldn't worry too much about the differences.

Comment: Should also point out that if you going it alone and already have your own fiefdom, you lose is it (as i understand it), because you become your husbands vassal.

Comment: @RossRidge I've started so many times over never knowing that. Dang. I'm female irl and was thinking of starting a male character just for shiggles to see how the game reacted... wish I'd had known that years ago!

Answer (score 2):

From my experience playing the game, playing as a female character could be considered the "Hard Mode" within Mount and Blade: Warband. It's less of a disadvantage and more of a way to give a challenge.

They have a unique way of getting Renown as well, but it could be a gamble:

If you counter a lord's remarks about you being a maiden, it is possible that you may get Renown for this due to them admiring a quick tongue and an equivalent wit. However, they may also lose relations with you, try to duel you, or even send their ***army*** at you. [[1]]

Overall, it's more of a way to make the game *much* more difficult than it is as a male character.

[Source](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Renown) (Last bullet in "You can gain renown in a number of ways:")

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the mods that allow you to control the garrsion of the spouse, then being a woman is an insane advantage. It means you can have an indefinite amount of troops without paying their wages (even their half wages).

This is also possible for men if one is playing a mod where female lords do exist (e.g. Clash of Kings with Asha Greyjoy, Maege Mormont et al). However, it is significantly more difficult to marry those (you'll probably have to be in the same faction first).

Though to be honest, this is quite gamey and could probably ruin the immersion and make the game a bit too easy.

Answer (score 0):

How the game mechanics work may vary by version/update for female toons.
I played version 1.1.72 as woman and and man both and noticed little to no  difference in renown gain. I did notice that in the 1.172  as soon as renown was 150 or more vassal and a fief was offered  by the king of the territory I was in  via messenger (neutral or positive in that faction ). I too noticed a difference in the response options for female toons when talking to lords . I suspect, but have not tested, getting a positive result will ( like capturing lords in battle)  depend in the fellows personality. Wiki fandom has a personality chart that allows  you to figure which lord has what personality by their first comments at meeting you (prior to merc or vassal in that lords faction) .
Character builds 6: 2 
female , 4 male. 1 noble 1 non on the gals.

Answer (score -4):

Well, the disadvantage I have encountered, is simply that during sparring  (a good way to give your troops XP BTW) on training fields, the female character wears a bikini and having people in the room you are in is awkward.

Comment: I think OP is looking for actual disadvantages. The way you feel looking at a digital female doesnt really count as an actual in-game disadvantage